# Min/max defined in Qt Designer not set for QDial instance

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qt4.8, qdial

I've defined parameters for the min/max of a QDial instance in Qt Designer like this (-100, 100, value=0):

[image: QDial in Designer]

When I start the application, the min/max parameters seem to be not set - they are 0, 100:

[image: QDial when executed]

When I set them expicitely in code, it works:

```
ui->dYAxisMove->setMinimum(-100);
ui->dYAxisMove->setMaximum(100);
ui->dYAxisMove->setSliderPosition(0);
ui->dYAxisMove->setValue(0);
```

I use Qt Designer 4.8.4:

[image: Qt Designer version]

Is it a known bug, or am I doing something wrong here?